# How to save the highest integer in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, counter

I have one label, named pointLabel, two buttons, named increases and decrease.

When you click "increase" button, it will increase the point in pointLabel. and you click "decrease" button, it will reduce the point. It will end when it reaches 0 point in pointLabel.

While the point is being increased or decreased, i would like to save the highest point and be able to retrieve it, so that i can show the highest point on another Label.

Please help

Here is the code of two IBActions

```
  - (IBAction)increase:(id)sender {

            count++;

            scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Point %i", count];
        }

  - (IBAction)decrease:(id)sender {

            count--;

            scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Point %i", count];
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30623761/907422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new property called maxCount or a variable:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger maxCount;`

Initialize it as `NSIntegerMin` in your initialization functions

when user taps increase button, check if the increased number is bigger and assign to `maxCount` if true.

EDIT: if you want to persist store the highest value:

```
- (IBAction)increase:(id)sender {

        count++;

        if (maxCount < count) {
            maxCount = count;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:maxCount] forKey:@"maxCount"];
        }

        scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Point %i", count];
    }
```

In other place, you could access `maxCount` and display it on another UILabel via:

```
NSNumber *maxCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"maxCount"];
NSInteger maxCountValue = [maxCount integerValue];
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( do you have solution for NSUserDefault or Core Data?

Comment: updated answer if you need the highest value for cache. Core data is quite a heavy framework to do such things.